# Javascript - Fetch array element parameter by function is undefined/null

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, null, split

The array element variable parameter fetched by my function is null/undefined?
Or it is all about the split function?
Thanks for the help guys!

Error :

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

JavaScript Code:

```
newData = "1,1,1,1,1/2,2,2,2,2|3,3,3,3,3/4,4,4,4,4";

var arrPage = newData.split('|');

arrRow = arrPage[0].split('/');
rowCount = arrPage[0].split('/').length;    

for(var i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++){

var rData = arrPage[0].split("/");
a = rData[i];
renderTable(a);
}

function renderTable(rData) {

var cData = rData.split(',');

var c1 = cData[0];
var c2 = cData[1];
var c3 = cData[2];
var c4 = cData[3];
var c5 = cData[4];
var c6 = cData[5];
var c7 = cData[6];
var c8 = cData[7];
var c9 = cData[8];
var c10 = cData[9];
var c11 = cData[10];
var c12 = cData[11];
var rowData = "";

rowData =   "<tr>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c1 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c2 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c3 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c4 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c5 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c6 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c7 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c8 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c9 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c10 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c11 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "<td>"+ c12 +"</td>";
rowData +=  "</tr>";


$("#acquisitionStatusList tbody").append(rowData);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the `arrPage[0]` apparently.

Comment: The source of this problem is the contents of `arrPage` which you do not show us.

Comment: @Loktar Actually it arrPage[0] has a value on my code. But for reference of issue. I have added a variable. Thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I edit again. arrPage has the value of ["1,1,1,1,1/2,2,2,2,2"].

Comment: On the latest edit, I have added the missing code to support the issue on the renderTable() function. Thanks!

Comment: @codefish06 - What you are doing is not cool.  You keep changing the definition of the problem by changing your code.  None of the current answers were written with the code you are now showing.  This is not a conversation.  You write a coherent question with the entire problem you want help with once.  You then clarify the problem if people are confused by what you're written.  But, you don't keep changing the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Sorry for it. I was just focus on the renderTable() function and missing needed variables.

Answer (score 0):

as the error message claerly says that `arrpage[0]` is empty.what you can do is check the array before using it in your code.

```
if (typeof array[index] !== 'undefined' && array[index] !== null) {
var rData = arrPage[0].split("/");
}
else
{
alert("empty");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have change the source code. At previous code, arrPage[0] have already a data from my project. What I want to focus is about the renderTable() function. Thanks for checking on my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this:

```
arrRow = "1,1,1,1,1/2,2,2,2,2";

arrRow = arrPage[0].split('/');
rowCount = arrPage[0].split('/').length;
```

Should look more like this:

```
arrPage = "1,1,1,1,1/2,2,2,2,2";

arrRow = arrPage.split('/');
rowCount = arrPage.split('/').length;
```

Where then arrRow would be:

```
["1,1,1,1,1", "2,2,2,2,2"]
```

and rowCount would be 2.

But as its written it doesn't make much sense... as to what you are trying to accomplish.  Lemme know if that gets you closer though...

EDIT

```
var newData = "1,1,1,1,1/2,2,2,2,2|3,3,3,3,3/4,4,4,4,4";
var newPage = newData.split("|");
//work with "first" page... maybe 
newPage.forEach(function(newRow) { ... } );
//or
var newRow = newPage[0].split("/")
//then if you think about it, it is newRow that you are feeding to your renderTable function
newPage.forEach(function(newRow) { renderTable(newRow); } );
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Sorry because I did not put the complete code for clear reference. Now I have added variables to support the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah with that @jfriend00 also already found it, but its your for loop you need to change the <= to an <

Comment: I have change the for loop issue, but still error occurs. Is there any issue on putting array element as parameter on functions?

Comment: Nah, give me perhaps just what you are trying to do with that array, in words... like your use case, and I'll show you the code to make it do that... something like:
Take that array, split by the pipe for new rows, split by the / for columns, etc...

Comment: This is the process:

Take the array and split it by | to get data for a page. Then split data by / to get the data for table rows. And then, split by , to be distributed on every $("table td"). 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See latest edit... you seem to have the basics but could re-write your code so it just reads clearer (assigning to a variable instead of constantly re-splitting) and you will be able to follow it through to your logic (since your needs are still not clearly expressed)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++){
```

needs to be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
```

You are going off the end of the array.

In addition, `cData` inside of `renderTable()` will only have 5 elements, but you're trying to access 12 elements.

---

Lots of other issues with your code too:

1. You're recalculating `arrPage.split('/')` four times.  Do it once and store the result.
2. Declare all variables to be either local or global with `var`.
3. Indent your code properly so it's a lot more readable.
4. There's no point in defining all those variables `c1`, `c2`, etc...

Comment: Thank you for answering and observing my codes @jfriend00

I have updated the reference code for clear idea of the issue. What I want to focus on this point is on the renderTable() function that fetched an array element as a parameter.

c1, c2, c3.. are done in purpose. After getting some data, each of them has condition based on their values.

Comment: @codefish06 - do you understand why you need to change the `for` loop to use `<` instead of `<=`?  As you have it now, it is feeding bad data to the `renderTable()` function and thus why you get an error inside of `renderTable()`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea on the for loop. I really understand on what you are explaining on it. But then, I change my source code to use '<', still the error occur. Is there any issue on putting array element as parameter on functions?